# Testosterone causes anabolism?

Tags: muscle-gain, testosterone

Does an increase in testosterone cause anabolism? If yes, what can cause it? (except from taking anabolic steroids and exercising)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about the natural fluctuations of T, the answer is likely No. It's a common idea that it's good to do leg day even for arms because squats and deadlifts give you high temporary levels of T (all exercise do, but squats and deadlifts use a larger amount of muscle.) This higher level of T is then supposed to be good even for your arms.

Studies where one group is training arms while one is training arms and legs do not show this effect however, the higher T levels in the latter group does not result in a higher muscle growth in the arms.

Comment: when I stated that it's impossible to grow muscles without training or taking anabolic steroids, I was told that any testosterone change can lead to muscle growth, how true is that?

Comment: It's false. T levels fluctuate for many different reasons. Also, your first statement is technically incorrect. Most people who add weight by adding calories add muscle mass (and fat mass.)

Comment: muscle mass with only calories surplus? is it very small amount?

Comment: or do u mean this added muscle mass will  come from the fact that daily activities will now use higher weight(fat mass)?

Comment: so the raise in testosterone itself doesn't cause anabolism?

Comment: No, calorie surplus alone, with 0 exercise, causes muscle gain in most people. Just like calorie deficit causes muscle break down in most people. It all depends on your current muscle mass levels of course. If a body builder would stop working out, stop taking T supplements and just eat a lot of food, the total muscle balance will most likely be negative.

Comment: No, temporary increases in testosterone does not cause long term anabolism. Both fat and protein is constantly both stored and lost, at every second. What matters is your total balance over a period of time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26055/discussion-between-herokiller-and-marten).